# Dissolve doesn't work with empty layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-9.3, dissolve, precondition

I have this model:[image]
The tool dissolve has this precondition of the Calculate Tool in order not to run with empty layers:[image] 
However, when it runs with a empty layer it returns the following error:

> ERROR 000953: Extent of the overlay operation will be empty. Failed to
>   execute (Dissolve).

I put the extent: union of imputs in every tool and in the model.

How can I run the model in this serie of layers (Layers_A),some of them with no features?

Comment: This documentation is from Pro rather than Desktop but perhaps it will help: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00951-00975-000953.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get Count alone to prevent a tool from running if a dataset is empty:

[image]

Comment: Thanks GISGe. Unfortunately I work with ArcGIS 9.3 and the Stop tool isn't avalaible. Is there a similar tool in ArcGIS 9.3?

Comment: Actually I've realized Get Count alone works too. Stop is new to 10.0. I've edited my answer! It works with 9.3.1, can you confirm it works with 9.3 too?

Comment: It works perfectly with 9.3. Thank you GISGe.